# API for Plone 4?

Tags: plone

I am wondering if Plone 4 has an API. I don't see one documented on api.plone.org.

Essentially what I would like to do is pipe content to a Plone page. We have a number of lookup tables in MySQL which if their content could be ported to Plone would allow the content to be found and indexed in Plone. These tables are updated about four times a year so each time it is piped it would become a new version of the same document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

api.plone.org is outdated.

If you want to know how to program Plone with Python read here:

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

However Plone is not different from any other Python program. You can use standard Python MySQL libraries and frameworks with Plone.

There exist a framework for importing content to Plone called Transmogrifier:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.transmogrifier/1.0

And various subpackages:

http://plone.org/products/mr.migrator

http://www.slideshare.net/regebro/transmogrifier-migrating-to-plone-with-less-pain-2387600

Plone Conference 2011 had an example of importing Liferay CMS SQL data to Plone but AFAIK this presentation is not on-line yet.

Advanced Python skills needed in any case.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for answering the question. It's exactly what I need.

Comment: @Mark Another product that might help: [collective.table](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.table) seems suited to your use case.

Comment: Just to note that api.plone.org has been takied down.